# How to add three days to a given date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have one text box. When I enter a date with the format `MM/DD/YYYY` in that textbox and click outside the textbox I need to display the result as `MM/DD/YYYY+3` using JavaScript.

For example, if my date is 12/31/2013 then the result would be 01/03/2014.

Comment: Sorry, question is unclear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this link will help you to find the answer:

[adding-number-of-days-to-an-entered-date-in-javascript](http://www.codeigniter.in/blog/post/adding-number-of-days-to-an-entered-date-in-javascript).

Comment: While that link may contain the answers, it is preferable to include a brief summary here, rather than just a link. So the answer will remain useful to others, even if the link breaks/changes.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the excellent library [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) with which you easily can add three days to your original date.

In your case it would be something like:

```
var input = moment(myTextBoxValue);
input.add('d', 3); // input is now 3 days later
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest to program and best readable solution would be to use a dedicated library for handling dates, such as [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

There, you have got the [add function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) which allows you to add an arbitrary amount of time to a given point in time. E.g.:

```
moment().add('days', 7);
```

If you use the `moment` function to parse the time entered, use that as your source value, call `add` on it, and return it as JavaScript `Date` using the [toDate function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/), you get exactly what you want.

So basically it comes down to:

```
var sourceDate = moment(new Date(2013, 7, 8)),
    targetDate = sourceDate.add('days', 3),
    result = targetDate.toDate();
```

Then, `result` contains the `Date` object you wanted to have.

I'd prefer that over native JavaScript handling of `Date`, as it is way more readble and hence understandable.